# Is there a URL that can open a contact search?

Tags: drupal, search, urls

I'd like to know if it's possible to craft a URL that performs a Contacts search – Something akin to typing a name into the search box in the navigation menu.  For a non-functional example of what I mean, to search for "joe":

http://www.mysite.org/drupal/civicrm/?search=joe

The goal would be to have this URL result in the same page that results when I manually type "joe" into the search box in the navigation menu, and hit "enter".

I'm trying to develop a script in my operating system (at our organization, Mac OS and we all use apple iphones that I can use Workflow to make scripts for) that allows me to select text, like "joe", right-click it to open a menu, select the script that I've titled "CiviCRM Lookup", and then a browser window opens, and enters a url that includes "joe".  I can do all the above, except figure out what kind of URL would execute such a search in CiviCRM!

I'm using Civi 4.6.2 and Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via full text search which gives you slightly different results than contact, but might meet your needs. If you are logged in to the demo server,check:

http://d45.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=15&reset=1&text=joe&table=Contact&force=1

Comment: This works about as well as I could ask for!  Thank you.